# Read ASCII file which is a simple series of 2D arrays separated by string (Python pandas/numpy)

Tags: pandas, numpy, ascii, hdf5

I have a relatively large ASCII file (~300 MB) which has a pretty straightforward structure, but it's not organized like a "normal" sequential table so I'm not sure how best to read it in using python (ideally with pandas or numpy).

Basically it's a series of 2D arrays (all identical shape) listed one below the other in an ASCII file. However, before each 2D array is a string  indicating what object each table belongs to. So imagine:

objectA
0 0 0
0 1 1
5 0 2
objectB
0 1 2
3 4 1
0 0 1

and so on.

Are there functions in pandas or numpy that can automatically handle that kind of data?

P.S. I was given this ASCII file as is. What I would have done instead of saving it like this ASCII format is to use some kind of record array or 'lookup table' data structure, where given an object ID (the string currently preceding each 'mini-table/grid' in the ASCII file), you could simply access the corresponding 2D numpy array. I would save this record array as an hdf5 file instead of ASCII. This would have been more intuitive and cleaner for me I think.

Comment: Do you know the size of the arrays before reading the file?

Comment: The `numpy` readers will handle the numeric blocks fine (normal csv), but you'll have to do your own file reads to handle the string lines.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes the arrays are 200 rows by 12 columns.

Comment: @hpaulj I think I see what you're seeing (within a for loop with the usual 'f = open('filename','r')). Do you think you could include an example given my sample block above?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33697615/how-do-i-save-a-3d-python-numpy-array-as-a-text-file  is an older example of what I have in mind.  You can adapt it to your needs.  The key is the `loadtxt/genfromtxt` works with a list of lines, or a generator of lists.